# Could not find the function in the schema cache ( RPC supabase )

Tags: postgresql, rpc, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

Hi I have created a postgres function using the supabase ui with 4 parameters.
[see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM3KC.png)

**function definition is**

```
begin
  insert into public.rooms (created_by_id, room_manager_id, room_name, room_key,starting_balance,room_open,player_id_list)
  values (
    cbi,
    cbi,
    rn,
    rk,
    sb,
    true,
    ARRAY[] :: uuid[]
  );

  UPDATE public.players
  SET room_id_list = array_append(room_id_list, (SELECT id FROM public.rooms WHERE room_name = rn))
  WHERE id = cbi;
end;
```

public.rooms table has this row level policy check : `(auth.uid() = room_manager_id)` with role as `authenticated` for `INSERT`.

When i am calling this function from a nextjs api route function like this,

```
const cbi : string= session.user.id
const rn : string= req.body.room_name
const rk : string= req.body.room_key
const sb : number= req.body.starting_balance
let { data, error } = await supabase.rpc("create_room", {cbi, rn, rk, sb} );
if (error) console.error("rpc crete_room error : ",error);
else console.log("rpc create_room success : ",data);
```

This gives me an error ,

```
{
  code: 'PGRST202',
  details: 'Searched for the function public.create_room with parameter cbi or with a single unnamed json/jsonb parameter, but no matches were found in the schema cache.',
  hint: null,
  message: 'Could not find the function public.create_room(cbi) in the schema cache'
}
```

i have checked that the parameter names match with the paramater i am passing in the rpc args

UPDATE : Problem SOLVED

I found out that the values in the constants rn rk and sb were `undefined` which is why the rpc function was ignoring them. Once I made sure that those constants had actual values rpc was able to identify them as valid arguments and the function call worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify each parameter in the RPC call i.e:

```js
let { data, error } = await supabase
.rpc("create_room", 
    {"cbi":cbi, "rn":rn, "rk":rk, "sb":sb } 
);
```

Comment: Thanks this works. but i found the actual problem now. the values in the const rn rk and sb were undefined. I made sure first that those values were present and then only passed them to the rpc. supabase.rpc("create_room", {cbi, rn, rk, sb} ) syntax worked